# ProxyError while using "requests.post()" in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, http, proxy, python-requests

I try to call a java-based web-service in python code, using `requests.post()` as follows:

```
endpoint = 'http://**.**.**.**:8080/MyApp/services/Services/login'

def index(request):
    post = request.POST

    if request.POST.get('login_button'):
        qd = QueryDict(mutable=True)
        qd.update(
            inputPhoneNumber=request.POST.get('phone_num'),
            inputPassword=request.POST.get('password')
        )
        messages.info(request, '{}?{}'.format(endpoint, qd.urlencode()))
        response = requests.post('{}?{}'.format(endpoint, qd.urlencode()))
        result = response.json()
        messages.info(request, result)

    return render(request, 'login/index.html')
```

However, proxy blocks my request. I suspect that this happens because the web-service uses `http` protocol. After 30 hours of searcing, I could not find anything to solve this problem. I've tried changing `http` to `https` but that caused another error. For the record, I can access web-service's url by manuel on browser, but I cant, on django. The stack trace is:

```
ProxyError at /login/    
Request Method: POST
    Request URL: http://localhost:8000/login/

    Django Version: 2.2.3
    Python Version: 3.7.3
    Installed Applications:
    ['login',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles']
    Installed Middleware:
    ['django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware']



    Traceback:

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py" in _new_conn
      160.                 (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py" in create_connection
      80.         raise err

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py" in create_connection
      70.             sock.connect(sa)

    During handling of the above exception ([WinError 10060] Bağlanılan uygun olarak belli bir süre içinde yanıt vermediğinden veya kurulan
    bağlantı bağlanılan ana bilgisayar yanıt vermediğinden bir bağlantı kurulamadı), another exception occurred:

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py" in urlopen
      603.                                                   chunked=chunked)

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py" in _make_request
      355.             conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\http\client.py" in request
      1229.         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\http\client.py" in _send_request
      1275.         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\http\client.py" in endheaders
      1224.         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\http\client.py" in _send_output
      1016.         self.send(msg)

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\http\client.py" in send
      956.                 self.connect()

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py" in connect
      183.         conn = self._new_conn()

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py" in _new_conn
      169.                 self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)

    During handling of the above exception (<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000242A09F43C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Bağlanılan uygun olarak belli bir süre içinde yanıt vermediğinden veya kurulan
    bağlantı bağlanılan ana bilgisayar yanıt vermediğinden bir bağlantı kurulamadı), another exception occurred:

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py" in send
      449.                     timeout=timeout

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py" in urlopen
      641.                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py" in increment
      399.             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))

    During handling of the above exception (HTTPConnectionPool(host='***.**.***.***', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: http://**.**.**.**:8080/MyApp/services/Services/login?inputPhoneNumber=214123&inputPassword=321312 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000242A09F43C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Bağlanılan uygun olarak belli bir süre içinde yanıt vermediğinden veya kurulan\r\nbağlantı bağlanılan ana bilgisayar yanıt vermediğinden bir bağlantı kurulamadı')))), another exception occurred:

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
      34.             response = get_response(request)

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
      115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
      113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

    File "C:\Users\TOLGA\Desktop\PythonWebProjects\WebLogin\login\views.py" in index
      55.         response = requests.post('{}?{}'.format(endpoint, qd.urlencode()))

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py" in post
      116.     return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py" in request
      60.         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py" in request
      533.         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py" in send
      646.         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

    File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py" in send
      510.                 raise ProxyError(e, request=request)

    Exception Type: ProxyError at /login/
    Exception Value: HTTPConnectionPool(host='***.**.***.***', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: http://**.**.**.**:8080/MyApp/services/Services/login?inputPhoneNumber=214123&inputPassword=321312 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000242A09F43C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Bağlanılan uygun olarak belli bir süre içinde yanıt vermediğinden veya kurulan\r\nbağlantı bağlanılan ana bilgisayar yanıt vermediğinden bir bağlantı kurulamadı')))
```

Comment: usually problem is because server check header `User-Agent` for existing browsers but `requests` sends `"Python ..."`. OR `requests` need to use `Session()` to get and resend cookies.

Comment: A non-working proxy server has been defined. Maybe on OS level.

Comment: @furas how do I use Session() in my code? Can you give an example code block?

Comment: you have `Session()` in requests documentation: [Advanced Usage](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/)

Comment: @furas Well, I don't need cookies. As far as I can see, cookies are used to store some data. However, I want to send data to web-service and get a return value from it.

Comment: cookies are used to control user access. Sometimes when user has no correct cookie then it can't access some page. Cookies are needed if you want to login.